# Finding diagonals in a parallelogram

Tags: geometry

Given a parallelogram with $AB = b = 7$ cm, $AD = a = 5$ cm and $\cos \angle DAB = 1/7$.

Find $AC = q$ and $BD = p$.

[image]

I know I have to use the cosine theorem, but I'm confused because of the given $\cos \angle DAB = 1/7$. How do I deal with it?

$p = \sqrt{a^2 + b^2 - 2ab \cos(A)} = \sqrt{a^2 + b^2 + 2ab \cos(B)}$

$q = \sqrt{a^2 + b^2 + 2ab \cos(A)} = \sqrt{a^2 + b^2 - 2ab \cos(B)}$

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Here's [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question). Follow these guidelines to get help in this site. Specifically in this question, show your work on the problem, what have you tried? It's important to show you have really made an effort because this site discourage questions that look like "here, solve this question for me"

Comment: @jjagmath, thanks, I know that because I'm part of the StackOverflow community, but how can I tell what I've tried when I don't know how to interpret cos ∠DAB = 1/7. It is not in degrees. I read/watched videos where I learned that the sum of the adjacent angles should be equal to 180 degrees, but the angle is not in degrees. I also tried a few calculators, but they all represent the angle in degrees https://www.calculatorsoup.com/calculators/geometry-plane/parallelogram.php

Comment: You're not given the angle. You're given the **cosine** of the angle. For all you know, the angle could be in degrees, or in radians, but that's not relevant here.

Comment: What are $p, q, a, b$ in the formulas you wrote? They're not defined and don't appear in the problem figure.

Comment: @jjagmath, edited the image and the formula

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just put the given value in formulas:

$$p=DB=\sqrt{7^2+5^2-2\times 5\times 7\times\frac17}=\sqrt{74-10}=8$$

$$q=AC=\sqrt{7^2+5^2+2\times 7\times\frac 17}=\sqrt{74+10}=\sqrt {84}$$

Comment: Thank you very much! :)